# Replicate this text effect with css2 compatibility

Tags: html, css

I want to replicate the following text highlight effect with css2. the text at the right of the image "Cocktail Flow"
Also, one essential need is that it should allow the wrapping of the text to 2-3 lines.

I am using the following css but it fails to provide the desired result.

```
    background-color: red;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 5px;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<div><h1>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1></div>

div { max-width: 200px; font-size: 20px }
div h1 { background: red; display: inline; margin: 0; padding: 3px; line-height: 1.5em; color: white; *zoom: 1 }
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mreq/zUwVJ/)

Comment: this doesnt work as expected. i need to style a complete sentence with background color. that sentence can wrap into more than 2 lines. the above css code displays the highlight but as a complete box.. not like in the image

Comment: because the text is in 3 different span's. i want that effect in a single span such that the text is wrapped in 3 lines.

Comment: thanks for taking time to help out Petr. but this doesnt do the trick. if you try the css code i gave in the question, you will se that it turns out the same effect. without the hassle of the `<div>`. your latest answer does not provide left/right padding.

Comment: @amit: well I don't think there's an other way to style it. you'll have to wrap the lines in an element in order to set padding

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6294/discussion-between-amit-and-petr-marek)